# Can someone explain why only one of my functions prints to console?

Tags: c++

Here is my code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int tuna = 20; // this is global

//main function
int main()
{
    int tuna = 69; // this is local
    cout << tuna << endl;
}

//fish function
int fish() 
{
    cout << tuna << endl; // this should print global?
}
```

The `fish` function doesn't print to the console when I run it. I am not sure why and it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: How are you "running" it? `main` is the entry point of the program, so it's called automagically. You need to call `fish` yourself.

Comment: If that's the entirety of your code, you're never calling `fish()` and hence the code inside the method never runs.

Comment: It should print `20` and *would* if only it was given a chance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not calling `fish()` so it doesn't seem strange its body is is not executed.

Try with:

```
int main()
{
  fish();

  return 0;
}
```

because `main()` is the only possible entry point for your program and the only way to call other, user-defined, functions.

Answer (score 2):

Do you ever call the function (fish) ?  Not in your sample.

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't call it at all.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I'll hazard a guess at the downvote reason: the answer isn't even a complete sentence, and more importantly it does not make sense alone, it's not clear what "it" is from just the answer. A rule-of-thumb I like: answer should still make sense, even if question is edited.

Comment: @hyde Maybe it's just that I'm not a native English speaker, but 1. the answer is a complete sentence, 2. "The fish function doesn't print to the console when I run it." - so it's quite clear that "it" refers to the `tuna()` function. Anyways, this "question" isn't worth more than this answer.

Comment: I'm not native English speaker either, and Wikipedia is what it is as a reference, but checking from there, your answer is "a subordinate clause", which is not a *complete* sentence (but writing complete sentences is beside the point, content and clarity is what matters). But as you seem to say your answer isn't any better than the question, which has many downvotes, then why are you asking you the answer got downvotes too?

Comment: @hyde because this answer doesn't deserve to be voted down, perhaps?

Comment: Well, if you just can't see a possible justification for the downvote from my comments, why don't you ask at meta. Just link to this answer, and ask why would somebody downvote it. I'm sure someone there can explain it better than me.